# JSF two parameters from two inputText to one method

Tags: java, jsf

I have a method that takes x and y and add them together and return the result. 
Now first InputText will take x and second takes Y. But I want to pass both X and Y to the same method so that public int addNumbers(int x, int y) will be called and return it. Any idea how?
am very very new to JSF 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have a managed form

```
public DataFormBean{
   String number1;
   String number2;
   //setter getter + constructors
}

public ActionBean{
    DataFormBean dataBean;
    //setter + getter

    public String add(){
       // convert your number here to int and pass it to the method and set the result back to the baen
    }
}
```

You need to declare managed bean and do the injection

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputText value="#{dataBean.number1}" >
  <h:inputText value="#{dataBean.number2}" >
<h:commandButton action="#{actionbean.add}" >
</h:form>
```

**See**

- [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/)

Comment: hmmm i have the managed bean where the method I mentioned is defined. But I was wondering how u pass parameters to the method from xhtml page

Comment: yeh because usually I could just define an inputText and do #{beanName.method} but as for the 2 parameters I can't figure out

Comment: You need bind inputTexts to number1 and number2 as says Jigar Joshi, and in add action you just do something like getNumber1() + getNumber2(). You need add getter and setters in your bean

Comment: @sys_debug you don't pass parameters directly to the method signature. Component values are bounded to field values and updated during "Update model values" phase of [JSF2 Lifecycle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/). And then in backing bean you can use them in your action method.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, I should have the add method in the managed bean...then for each attribute or element in the page, I will get the value of that, and then perform the addition independently (by calling the function) without the need of passing it directly the parameters. I hope this is correct